Is 'brew install openjdk' compatible with Eclipse 2024-03?
As you can see below, JDK's installed with home-brew are not acceptable to Eclipse somehow. How to resolve?

Edit: I got slightly further using the Search... button, but while this satisfies the Add JRE screen, it still does not result in a working installation:

Edit: As requested, the contents of that directory:
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
total 1
drwxr-xr-x  31 wytten  admin   992 Jan 16 10:19 bin
drwxr-xr-x   8 wytten  admin   256 Jan 16 10:19 conf
drwxr-xr-x   5 wytten  admin   160 Jan 16 10:19 demo
drwxr-xr-x   9 wytten  admin   288 Jan 16 10:19 include
drwxr-xr-x  71 wytten  admin  2272 Jan 16 10:19 jmods
drwxr-xr-x  71 wytten  admin  2272 Jan 16 10:19 legal
drwxr-xr-x  58 wytten  admin  1856 Apr 23 10:01 lib
drwxr-xr-x   3 wytten  admin    96 Jan 16 10:19 man
-rw-r--r--   1 wytten  admin  1225 Jan 16 10:19 release

Edit: The Problems that won't go away:

Edit: After the initial excitement of installing sdkman wore off, I saw that it didn't actually fix my problem. I believe this means it is more of an Eclipse problem than anything else. I wish I had a dollar for every time I've seen the "java.lang.Object" problem in Eclipse over the last 20 years, but previously if I poked it a few times with a sharp stick, it would go away.

Please show the content of this folder?

Does the structure of the directory you entered looks different than /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home?

Did you set JAVA_HOME, and/or can you run whereis java in zh?

@howlger sorry I don't understand your follow-up question

@Mr.Polywhirl yes before starting Eclipse my JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home, as reported by /usr/libexec/java_home

macOS Java JDK paths normally have /Contents/Home at the end - like on your Java 21 path

Please show the content of /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.10 which should be similar to /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home.

Please provide the output of ls /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.10 in your post.

Personally I always use the Oracle JDK which can be downloaded as a 'dmg' and installs in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

Running brew install openjdk@17
Should place it here: /usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/bin/java
So your SDK path should be: /usr/local/opt/openjdk@17
Symbolic link
You could also sym-link it:
sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk\@17/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk

Caveat
As mentioned in the comments of the first reference,

sdkman is the way to go! Versions installed with brew are not recognized by Eclipse.

See also

macOS - How to install Java 17
How to install openjdk with brew?
How to set JAVA_HOME environment variable on Mac OS X 10.9?


There's two layers of sym links already, that in combination seem to do what you suggest:
`12:09:46$ pwd
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
12:09:47$ (cd openjdk-17.jdk; pwd)
/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@17/17.0.10/libexec/openjdk.jdk`
